# Mellin-like Transform of Whittaker function

Tags: nt.number-theory

In computing the $L^2$ inner product of a non-holomorphic Eisenstein series with a Poincare series, the following integral appears:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi my}y^{s+\frac{1}{2}}K_{s-\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi |m|y)\frac{dy}{y}$$
where $K_{s-\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi |m|y)$ denotes the Whittaker function, defined by
$$K_{s-\frac{1}{2}}(2\pi |m|y)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-(t+\frac{1}{t})\pi|m|y}\frac{dt}{t}$$
I am looking either for resources or for tips on how to proceed in computing this integral.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does $\pi|m|y$ in the exponent stand for? $\pi y$ times the absolute value of $m$?

Comment: Gradshteyn-Ryzhik, 6.621.3

Comment: @PeterHumphries: Many thanks for that helpful response!

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, yes exactly.